# How do I call the Instance of an Extended Model

Tags: magento-2.1

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to FDB\FreeSamples\Helper\SampleCategories::__construct() must be an instance of FDB\FreeSamples\Model\Checkout\Type\Onepage, instance of Magento\Checkout\Model\Type\Onepage\Interceptor given,
```

Model

```
namespace FDB\FreeSamples\Model\Checkout\Type;

class Onepage extends \Magento\Checkout\Model\Type\Onepage
{
}
```

I am attempting to the load class in a helper:

```
public function __construct(
        \FDB\FreeSamples\Model\Checkout\Type\Onepage $onePage
    ) {
        $this->_onePage = $onePage;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must inject  **`\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context`** at your helper class.

> ```
> namespace FDB\FreeSamples\Helper;
> class SampleCategories{
> protected $_onePage;  
>   ....
> public function __construct(
>   \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
>         \FDB\FreeSamples\Model\Checkout\Type\Onepage $onePage
>     ) {
>         $this->_onePage = $onePage;
>         parent::__construct($context);
>     }
>   ....
> }
> ```

Also `__construct()`  **`FDB\FreeSamples\Model\Checkout\Type\Onepage`**  does not define properly.

---

```
<?php
namespace FDB\FreeSamples\Model\Checkout\Type;

use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AddressMetadataInterface as AddressMetadata;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory as CustomerDataFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Form;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender;

class Onepage extends \Magento\Checkout\Model\Type\Onepage{


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerUrl,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $customrAddrFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\FormFactory $customerFormFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\DataObject\Copy $objectCopyService,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory $formFactory,
        CustomerDataFactory $customerDataFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Math\Random $mathRandom,
        \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $encryptor,
        AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
        AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,
        OrderSender $orderSender,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter $extensibleDataObjectConverter,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface $quoteManagement,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector $totalsCollector
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $eventManager,
            $helper,
            $customerUrl,
            $logger,
            $checkoutSession,
            $customerSession,
            $storeManager,
            $request,
            $customrAddrFactory,
            $customerFormFactory,
            $customerFactory,
            $orderFactory,
            $messageManager,
            $formFactory,
            $orderSender,
            $customerDataFactory,
            $mathRandom,
            $encryptor,
            $addressRepository,
            $quoteRepository,
            $extensibleDataObjectConverter,
            $quoteManagement,
            $dataObjectHelper,
            $totalsCollector
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: still getting the same error.

Comment: what type of error.. you have getting

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 8 passed to FDB\FreeSamples\Helper\SampleCategories::__construct() must be an instance of FDB\FreeSamples\Model\Checkout\Type\Onepage, instance of Magento\Checkout\Model\Type\Onepage\Interceptor given,

Answer (score 0):

if you want to extend **Magento\Checkout\Model\Type\Onepage** class,

Your **__construct()** method look like below in your **FDB\FreeSamples\Model\Checkout\Type\Onepage**,

```
<?php
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerUrl,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $customrAddrFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\FormFactory $customerFormFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\DataObject\Copy $objectCopyService,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerDataFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Math\Random $mathRandom,
        \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $encryptor,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender $orderSender,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter $extensibleDataObjectConverter,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface $quoteManagement,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector $totalsCollector,
        \FDB\FreeSamples\Model\Checkout\Type\Onepage $onePage
    ) {
        $this->_onePage = $onePage;
        parent::__construct(
        $eventManager,
        $customerUrl,
        $helper,
        $checkoutSession,
        $customerSession,
        $logger,
        $storeManager,
        $request,
        $customrAddrFactory,
        $customerFormFactory,
        $customerFactory,
        $orderFactory,
        $objectCopyService,
        $messageManager,
        $formFactory,
        $customerDataFactory,
        $mathRandom,
        $encryptor,
        $addressRepository,
        $accountManagement,
        $orderSender,
        $customerRepository,
        $quoteRepository,
        $extensibleDataObjectConverter,
        $quoteManagement,
        $dataObjectHelper,
        $totalsCollector
        );
    }
```